# Can we pause the debugging process in R?

Tags: r, debugging, mtrace

I wrote code which has been running for more than 12 hours and I run it by `mtrace()` and `go()` function (from the **debug** package). Now I want to pause this and go through the remaining process myself by pressing enter, is there a way to do that?

```
mtrace(main)
F<-main()
go()
```